# Are there any samples available for Google Shopping API?

Tags: sample, google-api-java-client, google-shopping-api

Is there any sample code available for Google Shopping API for java? I have tried to search but could not find anything. I have no idea from where to start coding for my Android project.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was about to link to the [Java samples for the Google APIs Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/GoogleAPIs#Search_API_for_Shopping) ...and then I clicked through the link and saw that there aren't any. *`head -> desk`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still looking for one? you can find it here : [java-examples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Search_API_for_Shopping)

Answer (score 0):

hi All that you are searching for is the Google Places API. And follow this link to get a better knowledge about how to use places api...
[Have a look at this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551028/using-google-places-api)

[Google Places Documentation and user guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)

Hope this helps...
Thanks...

Edit #1:

Sorry guys i got confused with the places api which also have ability to return the shopping list available nearer... Please [check this link and it may help you and also download the sample available there](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/content/sample-apps/java/)

Comment: The Google Places API is completely separate from the Google Shopping API. **There are also no Java code samples near either of your links.** -1

Comment: @Matt Ball i have re-edited my answer... Thanks for giving me the change to know about the one called shopping api...

Comment: The samples that you have linked are for Content API. That API is used for Merchants. I am talking about **Search API**. Thats a different API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a third-party Google Shopping API, I suggest checking out the [Google Shopping API](https://www.searchapi.io/google-shopping) from SearchApi. It also offers Google Product, Reviews, Offers, and other APIs dedicated to shopping. Additionally, it features integration code samples in various programming languages.

*Disclaimer: I work for SearchApi*