# finding nearby hotels in android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

Hello I am new in making GPS based application so please help me

I am making an application which find the nearby hotels(say 1km )according to user location and show the list of them with phone no.

How to go next after detecting the user location?

and  how will i get these hotels? is there any api or web service which provides this facility.

I found lots of similar questions there but they're still not clear to me.

if any one could explain this, it would be a great help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you are looking for the coordinates for hotels, then this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Jonas i m not looking for the coordinates for hotels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting nearby famous places, you have to use Google's [Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/). You will get complete information from the above link.

Also you can go through the discussion related to the same thing in [Using Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551028/using-google-places-api)

Search by category, with over 100 different categories offered, and an Autocomplete service: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html

You can see complete list of supported categories here : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem when i started my first location based app..:)try to reading this  :

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

and this :

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Hope it will help you...!!