# Android Location Based service show up nearby place based on user's route

Tags: android, location-based-service

I have this Android project i have to develop an application using location based service using google map and web service. in this application user will set source point to destination point so that user will get route. when user get this route this application will show up nearby shop based on user's route. My question is what method or algorithm to show up nearby shop based on user's route? help me by giving some instruction and need some recommendation of references or some explain or examples. please someone help me out. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Google Places API for achieving your task.

Please visit below links for more help:

https://developers.google.com/places/?csw=1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772037/3235048

Comment: thanks for help, but i want to display information about places nearby based on user's route not user current location. so if user get route, shop will show up around user's route

Comment: Use onLocationChanged() method in your example and recall the services when location changed.

Comment: im sorry if ididnt get it but what do you mean user current location or user travel route? because my problem is how to display place near from user travel route