# Search In Google Maps By Category

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to make google maps api to provide result of search by category as the nearest hotels available in certain range and i want also to control range , here is the code i started with , this code search when the use apply an address . i want this this to done when the user enter a certain category not by entering an address

```
protected void search(List<Address> addresses) {

Address address = (Address) addresses.get(0);
home_long = address.getLongitude();
home_lat = address.getLatitude();
latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

addressText = String.format(
        "%s, %s",
        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                .getAddressLine(0) : "", address.getCountryName());

markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

markerOptions.position(latLng);
markerOptions.title(addressText);

map1.clear();
map1.addMarker(markerOptions);
map1.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
map1.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + address.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:"
        + address.getLongitude());
 }
```

what the modification needed to be done in this code ?

Comment: I want to Search in google maps api by category , by getting the nearest places according to the provided category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1st option- You build your own DB with all the hotels and their locations, then reflect that on the map.

2nd option- you use [Google's Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete?csw=1). Here is a nice [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551028/using-google-places-api) about it.

Hope this helps :)