# How do I implement a location drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I would like to implement a location drop down menu, like the ones shown on [Airbnb.com](https://www.airbnb.com/) and [Postmates.com](https://postmates.com/).

I would like a user to be able to type in a location anywhere around the world, and show only results from that location.

I assume the location drop down menu has something to do with Google maps but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search / https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551028/using-google-places-api

Comment: What code do you have so far? What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you'd like to achieve is the Autocomplete function, this is available through [Google Maps Places API - Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).

Kindly see the sample in the snippet:

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });
  var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
  // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
  // bounds option in the request.
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
  autocomplete.setFields(
      ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

  document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
      .addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
        autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
      });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div>
    <div id="title">
      Autocomplete search
    </div>
    <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
      <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
      <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
      <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
    </div>
    <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
      <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="">
      <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict Bounds</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAj0aaMu_aY6xiDSWH0ac_4pqN_l-opwmI&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

There are also other use case of the Place Autocomplete that might help you:

[Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

[Place Autocomplete Hotel Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch)

[Place Autocomplete Restricted to Multiple Countries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries)

If you want to build your own UI, you may get the Place Autocomplete results programmatically via [Place Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service)

Hope this helps.

Comment: but google maps api is not free ?