# Android app, that shows a map with some places pinpointed and labeled with corresponding image

Tags: android, api, google-maps, maps

I am building an android app, and want a map showing certain places (GPS Coordinates) labeled with images specific for each place. I used the Google maps API for the map display. However, I do not know exactly how to approach showing (for example) cinemas on the map. Should I create my own data source or can I use an API for that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [google places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/). See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830149/using-google-places-api-in-android) for a discussion of how to use it on android.

Comment: To be more accurate, I wan to pinpoint the touristic places in my city. So, how do I know if Google places API contains such data ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your own data (lat, longs) for the POIs. Use Maps API Overlay to show them on the map.

Comment: And do u recommend the data to be local on the device or how exactly should it be implemented ?

Comment: I think I will use your approach, thanks ! but I have a question, after creating my own data of (lat, longs) how do I get nearby places given a certain location, should I just go through the whole table ?