# Retrieving location from Google map in android

Tags: android

I want to retrieve neary by locations from my current locations how can I do it...
For example
If I am In Ahmadabad city than give the list of all hotels of ahmedabad city
how can i do it
plz help me

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Google-Place-Api**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/)  for this.

There are nice tutorials for how to use this api in android.

[Part 1: Using Google’s Places API to Develop Compelling Location Based Mobile Applications](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/)

[Part 2: Using Google’s Places API to Develop Compelling Location Based Mobile Applications](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-2-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/)

Also SO questions:

[Using Google Places API in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830149/using-google-places-api-in-android)

[Using Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551028/using-google-places-api)

Blog:

[Introducing the Google Places API](http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html)

Comment: I think the OP means via GPS? How would Google Place work under 3G?

Comment: @sp-1986 - He has to pass current lat, long in his place search url.