# How to locate restaurants,hospitals near user on google maps in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Current Location and Nearby Places and Route between two places using Google Maps API in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl)

In my application i am able to detect user but further now I need to locate and show restaurants and hospitals on the map near user's location. So how shall I proceed with that now?

Comment: Use Google Place Api look at http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830149/using-google-places-api-in-android ..

Comment: Best example of using Google Places API so far http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/